# TypeError: u.readFile is not a function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, exceljs

I am trying to export some data with image into excel, but I'm getting the error TypeError: u.readFile is not a function. I have tried to use other methods like buffer and base64, but they are all showing the similar errors TypeError: XXX is not a function. Below is my code in app.component.ts . I'm using Angular 13.2.0, please take a
look at it, thanks in advance!

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';


 exportFile(){

    let workbook = new Workbook();
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('sheet1');
    let header = ['Days Ordered', 'Times Range', 'Total Spots', 'Air Date', 'Day', 'Time', 'Length', 'Sub Total'];
    worksheet.addRow(header);

    //add image
    const image = workbook.addImage({
      filename: 'assets/logo.png',
      extension: 'png',
    });
    worksheet.addImage(image, "A1:B3");

    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
      let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'AdReport'+'-'+new Date().valueOf()+'.xlsx');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do this way Its work

```
const imageSrc = ''; 
const response = await fetch(imageSrc);
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
let logo = workbook.addImage({
            buffer: buffer,
            extension: 'jpeg',
        });
  worksheet.addImage(logo, 'B5:C9');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).